# <span> cannot appear as a child of <select> in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, redux

I have created a select dropdown component, which I am using in a redux-form in a react-redux app. The dropdown works great, and I have no impact to performance, but in the browser I receive the following warning.

`Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <span> cannot appear as a child of <select>.`

I am not sure why I recieve this error, as I am not passing in any `<span>` elements. Here is the code I am using to create the select dropdown (options is an array of object that contains each option's attributes. option.text is a string value that will be viewed by the user. so it could be something like 'Option 1' or 'Option 2'.)

```
return (
  <select {...other}>
  <option /> {
    options.map((option) => {
      return <option key={option.value} value={option.value}>{option.text}</option>
    })
  } </select>
)
```

Any ideas on why I would be receiving this warning, and how I can rectify this. I am using react 0.14.3

Comment: Well, what is `option.text`?

Comment: google search picked up [this](https://github.com/glittershark/reactable/issues/177) "Upgraded to version 0.12.0 for reactable, and 0.14.3 for react/react-dom and haven't noticed any errors"

Comment: option.text is a string value that will be viewed by the user. so it could be something like 'Option 1' or 'Option 2'.

Comment: Is that the only select on the page?

Comment: @DaveNewton yes that is the only select on the page, and is being used within a form created using redux-form.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems that some extra spaces in your jsx syntax have created a `span`.
I've tested your code, and after a correct re-indentation the error disappeared.

Before with the error: https://jsfiddle.net/snahedis/69z2wepo/28561/

And after re-indentation: https://jsfiddle.net/snahedis/69z2wepo/28564/

Comment: I had the same error cause I had `;` after the `map` function ... like this: `{this.state.items.map((oneItem) => { ... })};`. Removing the `;` fixed my issue.

Answer (score 1):

You have a variable re-definition issue. Your map function parameter is called "option", so when you write `<option>`, react would try to treat the object referred by the variable `option` as a react class. Try this instead -

```
return (
  <select {...other}>
  <option /> {
    options.map((optionNode) => {
      return <option key={optionNode.value} value={optionNode.value}>{optionNode.text}</option>
    })
  } </select>
)
```

Comment: I don't think this is the cause of the issue, I substituted your code and I got the same error. Also, the dropdown renders and works fine (both when I use the parameter ```option``` or ```optionNode```, it just sends out a warning. While this warning does prevent any functionality in my application, its a nuisance and potential distraction for other developers that I would like to avoid.

Comment: Did you check the rendered hierarchy using react dev tools?